# Create PostgreSQL trigger using JDBC

Tags: scala, jdbc, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, playframework-2.0

I am trying to create a PostgreSQL trigger in a [Play2.0](http://www.playframework.org/) database evolution script. The sql code is relatively easy and runs fine in pgAdminIII:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    NEW.modified = now();
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

However, I get an error when running the evolution: `ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted
string at or near "$$ BEGIN NEW.modified = now()"`. The SQL code seems to get truncated at
the first semicolon encountered in the function. I am using the "9.1-901.jdbc4" JDBC driver for PostgreSQL.

**Update:**

The code in [Evolutions.scala](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/Evolutions.scala) (line 219+) performs a simple split on the `;`. Seems to be faulty in the framework itself:

```
// Execute script
s.sql.split(";").map(_.trim).foreach {
  case "" =>
  case statement => execute(statement)
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: The problem has been discussed [here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2010-03/msg00056.php) as well.

Comment: Please show us the Java code that creates the trigger.

Comment: The code that creates the trigger is not my own since the sql script is a [Play database evolution script](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Evolutions). I guess the (Scala!) code can be found [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/Evolutions.scala).

Comment: Most probably that framework splits up your statement by `;`. You need to tell it to run that String as a **single** statement, not a script. As I don't know that Play framework, I can't tell you how that has to be configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following thing.

```
    String sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ " +
            "BEGIN " +
                "NEW.modified = now(); " +
                "RETURN NEW; " +
                "END; " +
            "$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';";
    DataSource ds = getDataSource();
    try {
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
        st.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: And where would be the right place for the code? It needs to be executed before the evolutions are evaluated. The `Gloabal`'s `onStart` method seems to be the wrong place...