# How to create a trigger from hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a database that uses triggers. I must not change this use of triggers, because another application works also on this database.

Now I make a java application (using hibernate) that migrates data into this database.
For this reason I drop the trigger before I start my app:

```
DROP TRIGGER MYSCHEMA.TR_USER;
```

and I create the trigger again, after my app finished working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER MYSCHEMA.TR_USER
 BEFORE INSERT
 ON MYSCHEMA.BDV_USER
 REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    SELECT MYSCHEMA.BDV_USER_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :new.ID  FROM dual;
END;
```

Now I want to integrate the deletion and creation of the trigger in my hibernate app.

I succeed to delete the trigger inside the app with:

```
String tmpStr = "DROP TRIGGER MYSCHEMA.TR_USER";
Query executeQuery = getSession().createSQLQuery(tmpStr);
ival = executeQuery.executeUpdate();
```

But when I want to to the same with the script for deleting the trigger, I fail.

How can be done this?

Thanks!

Comment: and where is your Script Code ?

Comment: "I succeed to delete the trigger" ... "I want to do the same with the script for deleting". What works ? What doesn't ? Please add the code that fails, and tell us how it fails (exception ?). Please also note that in a Hibernate app, nothing prevents you from accessing the database using raw JDBC if something can not be achieved through hibernate.

Comment: [This is how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10555360/4586674) you can create trigger using jdbc connection. Use Session.doWork() to access jdbc connection from hibernate.